# RGB and Palette Colors in GIMP

Tags: print-design, gimp, rgb

I am learning GIMP since I've started to print my t-shirts.

My question is how can I keep the colors of an image after Maximize RGB?

For example for an image with a rainbow, I am taking out the background then save the image in Maximize RGB. Colors become more red and blue, but I want to keep original colors.

Comment: Then do not use "Maximum RGB"?

Comment: Can you please show some example images of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

May be describe really what you want to do (with example pictures) because Maximize RGB is likely **not** the way to do it. If you want to reduce the number of colors in the picture:

1. `Color>Posterize` but this will find the most common colors
2. Create a palette with the color you want, then `Image>Mode>Indexed`, check `Custom palette` and give your palette. Try the dithering options.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Meanwhile I've found out what was going on. I wasn't aware that every image I'll save from GIMP will be automatically be in RGB. And because I didn't know, I was converting every image in Maximize RGB (the instruction were like if you use Photoshop, save image in RGB; for alternatives like GIMP do the same). Now is great, because all my images are keeping their colors. Thank you again and all the best!